# How can strcmp compare values at addresses without the * operator?

Tags: c, pointers

Does `strcmp` check the value at address even without the `*` operator? If yes, how are we able to compare normal strings using `strcmp`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *name;
    char *str;
    char a[] = "Max", b[] = "Max";
    name = a; str = b;
    printf("Add 1: %p Add 2: %p\n", name, str);
    if (!strcmp(*name, *str))
        printf("Names Match\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The desired output is not obtained if I compare the values at address using the `*` operator. However, if I remove the `*` operator, it works fine.

Comment: "If yes, how are we able to compare normal strings using strcpm?" what does that mean? Whats a "normal string"?

Comment: `strcmp(*name, *str)` is an error. Please check compiler output, change compiler settings if you do not see error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is your friend

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 ); 
str1 - C string to be compared. 
str2 - C string to be compared.
```

And you have

```
char *name;
char *str;
```

so

```
strcmp(name, str)
```

Is perfectly valid - you pass pointers to function - not dereferenced strings.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you think that `strcmp()` cannot dereference the pointers?

The way it wokrs, is that you pass a pointer to a string and it then dereferences the string to compare character by character returning the difference between the two first diffrente characters, or at least that is in principle how it does.

Dereferencing the pointer, does not give the address. I believe you are confused with the `&` address of operator. A pointer, stores the virtual memory address for some data, you then can access that memory with the `*` dereference operator.

In contrast, if you have a variable and you want the virtual memory address where it's stored then you use the `&` operator.

Since you are already passing a pointer, then you are giving `strcmp()` the address where it needs to start reding characters from to compare.

Also, because integers are convertible to pointers and viceversa, you can pass the value at the beginning of the string like this

```
strcmp(*name, *str);
```

the result of such operation is undefined for multiple reasons, one being that `*name` is not a valid address and hence dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

Although this compiles, if you enable compilation warnings you should notice that the compiler complains about it, because it's a really undefined thing to do.

Regarding what a string is and how it's represented in memory, you can only pass a pointer to a string to any function, because it's the only way to pass arrays to functions, and it might be a pointer even before passing it. In fact, passing the value like you did would not allow `strcmp()` to know where the string is and therefore it would be impossible to compare more than a single character.

Comment: The question is **Why the F* does it compile?**.  This kind of problem should be diagnosed as an error and the code should be refused. Why does the C Standard allow that?

Comment: @chqrlie why does the C standard allow what?

Comment: @M.M: my question is *Why does the C Standard not specify that programs containing constraint violations should not translate successfully?*  The only case where it specifically guarantees this behavior is if the programs contains an active `#error`.  Beyond this special case, the Standard does not have a conceptual difference between warnings and errors. It is up to the compiler implementors to chose which kind of problem cause failure to translate.

Comment: @chqrlie that seems like a useless prohibition to me, as in implementors would probably ignore it. Users can specify switches to get that behaviour if they want.

Comment: I think it is because they are not really forbidden, they have their use cases. The warning is useful to know that it was intended, and not an accident. That is why warnings can be deactivated individually. Perhaps, errors can be made more specific, for instance assigning a pointer to a integer that is too small could probably generate an error instead of a warning, but in my very personal opinion, starting to treat ones as if they were special, would cause any number of special cases that would make it impossible to define a standard.